# WebRTC TURN server ip range access restrictions

Tags: webrtc, restrictions, turn

We have a STUN/TURN Server (coturn) running. It will relay (over TURN) a video feed from a device on the internet to a device in a fixed IP range. (There is currently no stream in the other direction, but this might change in the future)

I know about the TURN REST API spec to generate temporary credentials to access the TURN Server. Now we would also like to restrict access in a more fine grained way: Is it possible to restrict the TURN server such that only streams TO a device in a certain IP range or streams FROM a device in this certain IP range is relayed and all other traffic would get dropped?

Is there a way to configure this in coturn or would it be possible to put a NGINX proxy in between to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

Expert from `coturn` [docs](https://github.com/coturn/coturn/wiki/turnserver), one of the optional parameters while starting the TURN server:

> **--denied-peer-ip=**`<IPaddr[-IPaddr]>`,
> **--allowed-peer-ip=**`<IPaddr[-IPaddr]>`  - Options to ban or allow specific ip addresses or ranges of ip addresses. If an ip address is
> specified as both allowed and denied, then the ip address is
> considered to be allowed. This is useful when you wish to ban a range
> of ip addresses, except for a few specific ips within that range. This
> can be used when you do not want users of the turn server to be able
> to access machines reachable by the turn server, but would otherwise
> be unreachable from the internet (e.g. when the turn server is sitting
> behind a NAT). The allowed/denied addresses (white/black lists)
> functionality is very simple:
>
> - If there is no rule for an address, then it is allowed;
> - If there is an explicit allowed rule that fit an address then it is
>   allowed - no matter what;
> - If there is no explicit allowed rule for
>   an address, and if there is a denied rule that fits the address, then
>   it is denied. The "white" and "black" peer IP ranges can be
>   dynamically changed in the database.

Comment: I have seen this in the docs but it does not fit my use case exactly as far as I understand it. If I would for example add the "specific ip range" as allowed-pee-ips, no other devices could connect to the TURN server. My problem is that one of the devices could have whatever IP it wants and the second party is always in a certain range. So I would need to filter allowed-peer-ips based on their origin or destination of the traffic.